# Avoid background widgets events with overlay view

Tags: android, android-layout

Have a look on following screenshot.

[image: Layout]

In this layout, I'm displaying overlay view (the one with pink color) to disable the log in button click until loading is complete. But the problem is that, though overlay view is appearing above login button but still login button click is called. Any idea whats happening here?

Following is my overlay view xml.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#88ff0000">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/loader_bg">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Just a moment..."
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <ProgressBar android:id="@android:id/progress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="?android:progressBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/loading_wheel"/>
        </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it my self.

Android dispatches events to background widgets if there are not implemented for the overlay events. So simply add on click listener on the overlay view to avoid click on Login button.